# PrimeFaces - Relationship between <p:rowExpansion> and <p:rowToggler>?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 4.0. I'm starting to get a feel for this, but can't seem to get it straight, and the documentation hasn't helped much with this specific question.

Can someone explain the relationship between these two components? Does `<p:rowExpansion>` dictate what is displayed when `<p:rowToggler>` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what confuses you, but inside `<p:rowExpansion>` you put the content which will be displayed when `<p:rowToggler>` is clicked. You've probably seen examples, but I'll put one here just for reference (taken from [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml))

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Expand rows to see detailed information
    </f:facet>
    <p:column style="width:16px">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Id">
        ...
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value" style="width:300px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/car/#{car.brand}-big.gif"/> 
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="Id:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            ...
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```